# serialize object date/time

Tags: c#

I have one problem. I have to serialize an object and that sam object is converted to XML, but it's a datetime object.

Ok, i have string variable which is filled with data from some sql query, like this

//DateDeliveryRequest

```
 if (rw_mat["dat_pot"].ToString().Length <= 0)
     {
           date_req = "";
     }
     else
     {
           date_req = rw_mat["dat_pot"].ToString();
     }
```

Now, date_req is being passet to object like this:

```
var dtfi = new DateTimeFormatInfo { ShortDatePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy", DateSeparator = "-" };
Agr3PL.DataArea.Header.DateDeliveryRequest = Convert.ToDateTime(date_req, dtfi);
```

And at the end this object with among other is being passed to serialize function:

```
 private string SerializeAnObject(object obj)
            {

                System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

                System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

                System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

                try
                {

                    serializer.Serialize(stream, obj);

                    stream.Position = 0;

                    doc.Load(stream);

                    return doc.InnerXml;

                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    WriteErrors.WriteToLogFile("WS.SAVE_DOK_SERIJALIZACIJA", ex.ToString());

                    throw ex;

                }
```

So i want to get datetime variable to xml but I don't, the xml has to look something like this(It is just a segment)

```
- <Header>
  <MessageType>COR</MessageType> 
  <UniqueHeaderNumber /> 
  <UniqueHeaderNumberFromWMS /> 
  <CompanyCode /> 
  <OrderNumber /> 
  <InvoiceNumber /> 
  <MovementNumber /> 
  <ReceiptNumber /> 
  <DebitNoteNumber /> 
  <PickNoteNumber /> 
  <LoadNumber /> 
  <DropSequence /> 
  <BulkPickNoteNumber /> 
  <NumberOfPallets />
  <DateDeliveryRequest />
```

But the problem is that the xml is not showing the node >DateDeliveryRequest it's not there
I don't get error just there is no node >DateDeliveryRequest???

I don't know is it the problem in serializer function or on something else, maybe in formating date or something else?

Comment: can you show Agr3PL.DataArea.Header class?

Comment: This is a part from where is it inhirited [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="date")]
    public System.DateTime DateDeliveryRequest {
        get {
            return this.dateDeliveryRequestField;
        }
        set {
            this.dateDeliveryRequestField = value;
        }
    }

Comment: while debuging can you see that DateDeliveryRequest is really set?. Maybe you need to try DateTime.Parse() instead  Convert.ToDateTime()

Comment: I tried this  Agr3PL.DataArea.Header.DateDeliveryRequest = DateTime.Parse(date_req, dtfi); and I can see that value is being set into the DateDeliveryRequest, there is no error but in xml document there in no nod DateDeliveryRequest, it's missing, like it's deleted or something

Comment: Tested. Everything works fine for me

Comment: Hey, do you have somekind of e-mail so that I can send you code, how did you tested??? I still can't get xml node DateDeliveryRequest??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this code:

```
public class Test
{
    private DateTime dateDeliveryRequestField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "date")]
    public System.DateTime DateDeliveryRequest { get { return this.dateDeliveryRequestField; } set { this.dateDeliveryRequestField = value; } }
}

private string SerializeAnObject(object obj)
{
    System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
    System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    try
    {
       serializer.Serialize(stream, obj);
       stream.Position = 0;
       doc.Load(stream);
       return doc.InnerXml;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

Test n = new Test();
n.DateDeliveryRequest = DateTime.Parse("2012-10-07");
string result = SerializeAnObject(n);
```

and result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <DateDeliveryRequest>2012-10-07</DateDeliveryRequest>
</Test>
```

So everything looks good.

Comment: Ok, thaks, it seems that code is working but i got this <MessageType>COR</MessageType> 
  <UniqueHeaderNumber /> 
  <UniqueHeaderNumberFromWMS /> 
  <CompanyCode /> 
  <OrderNumber /> 
  <InvoiceNumber /> 
  <MovementNumber /> 
  <ReceiptNumber /> 
  <DebitNoteNumber /> 
  <PickNoteNumber /> 
  <LoadNumber /> 
  <DropSequence /> 
  <BulkPickNoteNumber /> 
  <NumberOfPallets /> The nod <DateDeliveryRequest> it's like the serializer didn't serialize it, the node isn't there, like it's deleted or something else

Comment: Can you add all code to pastebin? Maybe then we could find the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I don't wont to bother you any more, I think it's a problem in serialzizer, i have to write it diferently.

Answer (score 1):

To serialize dates use this string format

```
date_req = rw_mat["dat_pot"].ToString("s");
```